# What could cause an Icom IC-756 Pro II to suddenly stop transmitting?

Tags: hf, transceiver, icom, equipment-troubleshooting

My HF radio (Icom IC-756 Pro II) suddenly won't receive or transmit. I recorded the sound it makes when receiving and uploaded it to https://w7bkg.org/wiki/File:Radio_Issue.wav . It sounds the same on all frequencies it covers (160 m to 6 m), and having an antenna or not makes no difference. I've tried with two different antennas. It won't even receive any of WWV's frequencies with an antenna that normally works very well. When I try to transmit (in ham bands; not on WWV frequencies), it shows zero power output. Audio is getting to it, because if I turn "monitor" on, I can hear the audio over the speakers.

It started doing this last night. It had been stored in our trailer storage compartment for a few months, and I just got it out yesterday. I made a few FT8 contacts on 40 and 80 meters, and sent an SSTV picture on 10 meters (28.600 MHz), and all of that worked fine. After sending the picture, I went back to 80, and IIRC received a few more signals before this started. The whole time, my dad was running 10 meter FT8 (14.074 MHz) with 65 W, with his antenna about 20 feet from mine at the closest point.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?